# How to access the value of cinemachine's camera distance in Unity / C#?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, camera, cinemachine

I'm working on Unity/C# now and I'm stuck with accessing CinemachineVirtualCamera's camera distance value in the script. What I'm trying to do is change the value of camera distance in the body section.
[image]

First of all, how can I access the CinemachineVirtualCamera component in this game object? The MoveScript is what I attached to a player game object, and I want to zoom out the camera depending on the player's movement. Since the game I'm making is small, I won't make other .cs files.

I wrote

```
public class MoveScript: MonoBehaviour
{
    private GameObject camObj;
    void Start()
    {
        camObj = GameObject.Find("Vertical Follow Camera");
        camObj.GetComponent<CinemachineVirtualCamera>(); // <- but I get error saying, The type or namespace name 'CinemachineVirtualCamera' could not be found 

    }
}
```

I also read [this document](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.cinemachine@2.1/api/Cinemachine.CinemachineFramingTransposer.html#Cinemachine_CinemachineFramingTransposer_m_MaximumDistance) and I think the `m_CameraDistance` is what I'm looking for but how can I access that value?

Answer (score 3):

For anyone else who wondering

```
GetComponent<CinemachineVirtualCamera>()
 .GetCinemachineComponent<CinemachineFramingTransposer>()
  .m_CameraDistance
```

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the linked document, these classes are in Cinemachine namespace. To access the classes you have to either add

```cs
using Cinemachine;
```

to the beginning of your script or change your script to

```cs
public class MoveScript: MonoBehaviour
{
    private GameObject camObj;
    void Start()
    {
        camObj = GameObject.Find("Vertical Follow Camera");
        camObj.GetComponent<Cinemachine.CinemachineVirtualCamera>();
    }
}
```

And as for accessing the `m_CameraDistance` variable, HuySora already answered that part

Answer (score -1):

Try this and don't forgot to mention namespace

```
public class MoveScript: MonoBehaviour
{
  private CinemachineVirtualCamera virtualCamera;
  private GameObject camObj;
  void Start()
  {
      camObj = GameObject.Find("Vertical Follow Camera");
      virtualCamera = camObj.GetComponent<CinemachineVirtualCamera>();
      float f = virtualCamera.m_CameraDistance;

   }
 }
```